# how to validate atleast one value in multiple text field using jquery?

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, textfield

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var errorExist = false;
     $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#form3").submit(function(){
     var get_count = $("#form3 input[type=text]").length;
       for(i=1; i<=get_count; i++){
         if($(".qtyy"+i).val()==""){
          errorExist  = "true";
        }
    }
  if(errorExist  == "true"){
      errorExist  = false;
      alert("Please enter value");
      return false;
   }
 });
});
</script>


    <form action="" name="form3" id="form3" method="post">
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy1" size="7" />
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy2" size="7" />
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy3" size="7" />
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy4" size="7" />
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy5" size="7" />
    <input type="submit" value="Place Your Order" name="postorder" id="postorder" />
    </form>
```

Comment: why you write this  var errorExist = flag++;

Comment: you declared errorExist two times check my code

Comment: replace errorExist = flag++;  with  errorExist  = "true";.This will solve you rproblem

Comment: before this i checked with your code, but not working.

Comment: it is working for me.Can u create a link

Comment: please give me a whole code with html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var errorExist = false;
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#form3").submit(function(){
     var get_count = $("#form3 input[type=text]").length;
         for(i=1; i<=get_count; i++){
          if($(".qtyy"+i).val()==""){

           errorExist  = "true";
          }
         }
     if(errorExist  == "true"){
      errorExist  = false;
      alert("Please enter value");
      return false;
     }
});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

 <form action="" name="form3" id="form3" method="post">
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy1" size="7" />
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy2" size="7" />
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy3" size="7" />
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy4" size="7" />
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy5" size="7" />
    <input type="submit" value="Place Your Order" name="postorder" id="postorder" />
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please mark it as answer if you got the solution with this answer :)

Comment: have you check this, its not validating the form

Comment: same problem not validating, please check.

Comment: why this showing alert for each blank text field rather this i want to show only one alert.

Comment: thanks for your efforts we are very close but only one problem is if i enter some value in any text field then it should not show any alert

Comment: please mark it as answer if you got the solution with this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I feel this is the logic you are trying to achieve.If any text box value is not blank the form should validate

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
   var errorExist = false;
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#form3").submit(function(){
     var get_count = $("#form3 input[type=text]").length;

     errorExist  = "true";
         for(i=1; i<=get_count; i++){
          if($(".qtyy"+i).val()!=""){

           errorExist  = "false";
          }

         }
     if(errorExist  == "true"){
      errorExist  = false;
      alert("Please enter value");
      return false;
     }
});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

 <form action="" name="form3" id="form3" method="post">
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy1" size="7" />
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy2" size="7" />
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy3" size="7" />
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy4" size="7" />
    <input name="qtyy[]" type="text" class="qtyy5" size="7" />
    <input type="submit" value="Place Your Order" name="postorder" id="postorder" />
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form3").submit(function(){
        $("> input[type=text]",this).each(function(){
            if($(this).val()==""){
                alert("Please enter value");
                return false;
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Comment: if you want an alert for each input, just remove the return false

Comment: its still validating the text field after entering some value